# Need to I.D. address

Tags: address

I am trying to I.D. the owner of an address.
The address is 18y1M4fCUDvKwqbmPKd1N5QLTTiAVQiUCf 
And they are drawing money out of my account.
Can anybody help?

ohbeone

Comment: You can't I.D. an address, however you can perhaps clarify some other things in your post. What software/site are you using? How do you observe money being drawn (Bitcoin doesn't support such a thing - if it happens, it's either theft or a misunderstanding).

Comment: You may have exposed your private key somehow

Answer (score 1):

It not possible to identify the person behind a wallet address. Maybe the address is written on a personal website or something like that. But if it isn't there's no way to get more info about the person behind that address.